# is it idiomatic to say "to walk / run / climb up straight, don’t slouch" like when we say "Sit up straight, don’t slouch."?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

> **[straight](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/straight)** (adv): 2 POSITION in a level or correct position
>
> Sit up straight, don’t slouch.

---

People often say "**Sit up straight, don’t slouch**" or "**Stand up straight, don’t slouch**".

My question is, can we replace "**sit**" with other moving verbs such as "**run / walk / climb**"?

It may be confusing because when we say "**he walks up straight**", people may think he walks upstairs in a straight line for example, not he walks with his back up straight.

is it idiomatic to say "**to walk / run / climb up straight, don't slouch**"?

Comment: I don't think so. *Walk straight* means walk in a straight line.

Comment: "Stand up straight when you are walking."